# Iterating over colors in a Seaborn kdeplot in Python inside a for loop

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to draw three different kde-subplots in a for loop and at the same time I would like that the different lines have different colors, but when I get this ErrorInvalid RGBA argument: ['#0B132B', '#6FFFE9', '#5BC0BE'].

I imagine when I am iterating the plots somehow I am not iterating over my 3-colors-palette. The lenght of the list and the palette Im iterating over are the same.

Is it possible that I get a different color for every line inside the for a loop so I dont have to do it manually?

```
age_classes = [age_class1, age_class2, age_class3]
age_sur = [train_data[train_data['Survived'] == 1].Age, train_data[train_data['Survived'] == 0].Age]
age_sex = [male_age, female_age]

fig, surv_age = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,5), nrows=1, ncols=3, sharey=False, sharex=True)

for c_age in age_classes:
    sns.kdeplot(c_age, ax=surv_age[0], shade=False, color=pal3)
    surv_age[0].legend(['First Class', 'Second Class', 'Third Class'])
for k_age in age_sur:
    sns.kdeplot(k_age, ax=surv_age[1], shade=True)
    surv_age[1].legend(['Survived', 'No Survived'])
for s_age in age_sex:
    sns.kdeplot(s_age, ax=surv_age[2], shade=True, bw=1.5)
    surv_age[2].legend(['Male', 'Female'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate over two arrays in parallel using `zip()`:

```
age_classes = [age_class1, age_class2, age_class3]
age_colors = ['#0B132B', '#6FFFE9', '#5BC0BE']
(...)
for c_age,color in zip(age_classes,age_colors):
    sns.kdeplot(c_age, ax=surv_age[0], shade=False, color=color)
    surv_age[0].legend(['First Class', 'Second Class', 'Third Class'])
(...)
```